# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, sapui5, wai-aria

I am trying to set "aria-selected=true" in a sap.m.table cell because I want screenreaders to read which cell is selected in the table.

```
row.addCell(new sap.m.VBox({
    items: [
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "cell one"
        })
    ]
).setAttribute("aria-selected", "true"));
```

However, i'm getting this error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).setAttribute is not a function".

I've tried fixing this by adding a semicolon after sap.m.Text but that gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setAttribute is not valid function for a Row.

However, it is a valid function for its Dom Reference. Try this

```
row.addCell(new sap.m.VBox({
    items: [
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "cell one"
        })
    ]
}).getDomRef().setAttribute("aria-selected", true);
```

Be aware that you can only get the dom reference from controls which are already rendered. If you want to set the attribute to the text control instead, you have to retrieve the text after its initialization and rendering before setting the attribute.